# Important Concepts I want to Hone my Understanding of

Tags: function, class, namespaces, computer-science, theory

So I've been programming for a little under a year now, and I've taught myself parts of Python, PHP, and Javascript. I'm really trying to become a better programmer and understand the theory behind programming (which seems, in essence, manipulation of information).

Basically it seems to write good code - it must be modular - this reduces complexity of programs, which in turn makes them easier to read and reproduce similar effects. This uses functions and classes.

What is the difference between a function and a class? It seems like they are both something that can have an argument passed through to it - I understand that a class is "higher" than a function.

What is a namespace? How does it differ from a variable? A data structure? Where can I find resources on this sort of information? I've looked on the internet, but a lot of it seems like gobblygook. I also already have my bachelor's, so I am not looking to go back for a second degree. I just want to become a better programmer at this point. I've done enough "hacking" that I get the basic concept, but the theoretical underpinnings still aren't all there.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: These are far too many different questions; in general, a SO post should focus on one particular topic...

Comment: But in general, if you're having difficulty on the distinction between a namespace and a variable, I strongly suggest picking up a decent beginner's book on the language of your choice.

Comment: @Oli, if you're working in JavaScript, the difference between a namespace, a function, and a variable is far from clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem with the question (which the relevancy police will probably be closing shortly) is that a lot of the terms you're using have different meanings depending on the language paradigm you're using. A function in PHP is a different beast from a function in JavaScript.

I recommend starting with "JavaScript: the Good Parts" for an understanding from the particular perspective of someone working in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Okay lets go from the top down:

A namespace is a logical ordering of code.

A real world analogy is that of a Library. A library contains all the books but it make sense to have sections of the library devoted to specific areas e.g. books (code) about physics

A Class is a model (almost always derived from real-world objects) which exposes functions and properties. Classes can (and should) encapsulate (hide) properties and functions which the developer doesn't wish other developers to be able to reach. Consider:

```
public class Car{

public Car(){}//default constructor.
public Car(int tirecount){//this constructor allows initialisation of the class to some 'safe' state
    Tires = new Tire[tirecount];
}
//properties 
public Tire[] Tires{get;set}//bad. at any point you can remove a tire from the car
public bool IsStopped{get;private set;}//safe. can check if car is stoppped outside class but can only change value inside car    

    //functions (...methods)
    public Start(){//starts car
        IsStopped = false;
    }
    public Stop(){
        IsStopped = true;
    }
    public RemoveTire(int tireIndex)
    {
        if(!this.IsStopped)this.Stop();
        Tires[tireIndex].Remove();//safe to remove tire when stopped
    }
}
```

In order to get code re-use and polymorphic behavior you must read about interfaces. Interfaces allow the definition of a contract. The internal implementation of the contract can change but the methods already defined cannot be changed without breaking the original code that relies on that contract. Extra agreements can be added without breaking old implementations. Example:

Class Man implements ITalk
Class Dog implements ITalk

ITalk contract states 'I have function 'Speak' i.e.

```
interface ITalk{
     void Speak();
}

class World
{
    List<ITalk> beings;

    public World(List<ITalk> beingsToPopulateWorldWith)
    {
        beings = beingsToPopulateWorldWith;
    }

    public void MakeAllAnimalsTalk()
    {
        foreach(var b in beings)b.Speak();//because we know all object in the beings list use the ITalk interface (contract) we KNOW that we can call .Speak(). What each ITalk does in speak is up to them but we know we can call it.
    }
}
```

So Man.Speak() may output "Hi" and Dog.Speak() may output "Woof".

Classes can also extend so consider the Man/Dog example. Their base class could be Animal. Animal defines IsAlive. Man derives from Animal so gains IsAlive as does Dog however Man could then define alternative behaviour i.e. AbilityToMakeTools than that of dog.

I find that as soon as you start to envisage classes as real world objects/processes (everything can be modelled even the most abstract 'thing') then classes start to make logical sense.

HTH

Comment: I'd also like to state that these principles are language agnostic i.e. they apply in almost all modern OOP languages. Javascript is no exception. Even though all things are functions(){} these functions can also be made to behave just like classes through use of 'closures'.